# Python 2.7 customizing garbage collection behavior

Tags: python, cpython

I have a python class where in its init calls Cpython code allocating memory using c++ constructs in memory data store.

I want to delete the newly created element in the data store when the corresponding python object gets garbage collected.

I looked into gc documentation, I found thé callable feature. But it’s supported since python 3.3 and I use 2.7.

So is there an alternative to the callable feature ?
Thanks

Comment: You really really should not use 2.7 anymore, except you need it to work with outdated libraries

Comment: It’s kinda not an option

Comment: It might not be in your hands, but your organization should really give up on Python 2 already. By the original timeline, it would have been end-of-lifed last April. https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternatrive:

I simply did override `__del__` function in Python class to call a Cpython extension function that frees the corresponding object.